# Can one Python project use both 2.x and 3.x code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm going to start on a long (~1-year) programming project in Python. I want to use wxPython for my GUI (supports 2.6), but I also want to use 3.1 for the rest of the project (to start using the 3.x syntax).

Is there any way for me to design a project that mixes 2.x and 3.x modules? Or should I just bite the bullet and use either 2.x (preferred, since I really want to learn wxPython) or 3.x throughout?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: The 2to3 utility converts your Python 2 to Python 3.   Why "mix"?  Why not just write Python 2 and convert?

Comment: A (beginner's) hunch that tells me if 2.x to 3.x conversion were as easy as 2to3, all the big libraries would have done it the day 2to3 came out. That (much more accomplished) programmers like those behind wxPython have yet to port their libraries makes me think the translation is challenging, even for something as basic as my project.

Comment: @Begbie00: I'm not sure you have that right at all.  It **is** as easy as 2to3.  Not everyone actually cares, however.  Some author's are too busy with other things to get their Python 2 packages ready for Python 3.   Consequently, not everyone has upgraded everything so that the 2to3 utility will work.  You, however, are starting fresh.  Why not use 2to3 as instructed by the Python web site? Why "mix"?

Comment: Ah, good perspective. Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Begbie00: I'm not providing an answer, I'm asking for clarification.  Why "mix"?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The 2to3 script will convert your *.py files, and seems to work just fine.  But it doesn't convert C extension modules.  That's what's taking most of the effort in libraries being ported to 3.x.

Comment: @S.Lott: mixing the ability to use wxPython (2.x) + with learning new syntax (3.x)
@dan04: interesting, thanks

Comment: @Begbie00: You are trying to both implement something in Python 2 and learn Python 3 syntax?  At the same time?  Is that what you're calling "mixing"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2 and 3 are not that different. If you have learned Python 2 well, it will be a matter of minutes to get acquainted with Python 3. The official recommendation says that you should use Python 2.6 (the current version) and try to be forward-compatible. Python 3 is currently not an option for large projects as virtually none of the popular packages have been translated yet. But development of Python 2 and 3 will continue in parallel for a long time, so you won't lose much by not using Python 3. You can import many syntactical features of 3 (Unicode string literals, division, `print` function, absolute imports) using the `__future__` module, and the standard library remains mostly the same. So I'd recommend using Python 2.

Comment: bad recommendation from today's perspective ;)

Answer (score 5):

You should use python 2.7 (a release candidate is expected in the next days) that is very close to python 3.1 and to  code taking care of no using deprecated features. There is a recent version of wxpython for python 2.7.
After wxpython gets 3.1-3.2 builds, conversion of the code should not be too hurting.
Still, wxpython has [no deadline for the transition](http://wiki.wxpython.org/TentativeRoadmap)  :-(

Another option is to use [pyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) that already has builds for python 3.1

Comment: +1 for pyQt.  pyQt also currently has the advantage of a better availability on Mac OS X (it's available through Fink, while wxPython is not).

Answer (score 2):

> mixing the ability to use wxPython (2.x) + with learning new syntax (3.x)

Don't "mix".

Write Python 2.  Get it to work.

Play with Python 3 separately.  Don't "mix".

When the various packages and modules are available in Python 3, use the 2to3 conversion to create Python 3.  You'll find some small problems.  Fix your Python 2 so that your package works in Python 2 and *also* works after the conversion.

Then, you can drop support for Python 2 and focus on Python 3.

Don't "mix".